# "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders" (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, audio, babel-loader, expo-av

I am working on a **Bare React Native** audio player hybrid(web and android) app with a **TypeScript** template.
After I implemented **expo-av** and tried to compile it on the web I got this:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio/Recording.js 134:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (134:46)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|       this._canRecord = false;
|       this._isDoneRecording = true;
>       this._finalDurationMillis = finalStatus?.durationMillis ?? 0;
|       _recorderExists = false;
|
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const createExpoWebpackConfigAsync = require('@expo/webpack-config');

module.exports = async function(env, argv) {
    const config = await createExpoWebpackConfigAsync({
        ...env,
        babel: {
            dangerouslyAddModulePathsToTranspile: ['@ui-kitten/components']
        }
    }, argv);
    return config;
};
```

**package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.4",
...
}
"devDependencies": {
"@expo/webpack-config": "^0.12.58",
"@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
...
}
```

Here is my repository if that would help:
https://github.com/VelislavP/MeditationAppReactNative

The file that uses expo-av is: `MeditationAppReactNative/src/screens/meditations.tsx`

How may I fix this?
Thanks in advance.

---

[THIS IS JUST FOR ADDITIONAL INFO AS I FOUND THE ROOT OF THE PROBLEM AND ISN'T A SOLUTION]

The actual problem was:

```
./node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio/Recording.js 134:46
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (134:46)
```

So I went to Recording.js and changed:

```
 this._finalDurationMillis = finalStatus?.durationMillis ?? 0;
```

to this:

```
this._finalDurationMillis = finalStatus.durationMillis;
```

And in every other file where there was an error of this sort it was the question mark's fault.

I think it has to do with the fact my project is with a Typescript template and expo-av downloaded itself with typescript configuration, but for some reason, it is in a .js file, and js doesn't like "?."(used in typescript if you are not sure something exists) so by removing it now the app works.

Answer (score 1):

Editing node_modules is not a good solution.
This problem is because of the nullish coalescing operator.
I have never done like this in React Native project, but I will leave here one solution helped me in React project.
I hope this help any others who faced the similar issue.

In my case, it was helpful to load a new package `@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators`.

I was using `@craco/craco`, so it was pretty simple to load this package.

In my craco.config.js file, I've added these lines.

```
babel: {
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators"
  ],
},
```

You can see the details of discussion about this issue from this link.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9908